# Updating labels on secondViewController with data from tableViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, back-button, reloaddata

I have a tableView as initial controller and few labels in secondViewController.
When I create a cell with data I want, the idea is to display that data in the secondViewController labels. All works fine, BUT, the labels in the secondVC update only when I hit the back button, to go back to the table view and select the row again.
How can I update the data displayed in the secondVC on the first tap in the tableview cell?

```
enter code here
```

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var titles = [String]()
var subjects = [String]()
var previews = [String]()
var textFieldsText = [UITextField!]()

var selectedTitle: String!
var selectedSubject: String!
var selectedPreview: String!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Add, target: self, action: "addTitle")


}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = titles[indexPath.row]
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = subjects[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return titles.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    selectedTitle = self.titles[indexPath.row]
    selectedSubject = self.subjects[indexPath.row]
    selectedPreview = self.previews[indexPath.row]
    tableView.reloadData()

}
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showPreview" {
        let dataToPass = segue.destinationViewController as! previewViewController
        dataToPass.titlesString = selectedTitle
        dataToPass.subjectsString = selectedSubject
        dataToPass.previewsString = selectedPreview

    }
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func addTitle()  {
    let addAlert = UIAlertController(title: "New Title", message: "Add new title, subject and a short preview", preferredStyle: .Alert)

        addAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))

        addAlert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler {[unowned self] textField in
            textField.placeholder = "Add Title"
            textField.textAlignment = .Center
            self.textFieldsText.append(textField)
            }
        addAlert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { textField in
            textField.placeholder = "Add Subject"
            textField.textAlignment = .Center
            self.textFieldsText.append(textField)
            }
        addAlert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { textField in
            textField.placeholder = "Add Short Preview"
            textField.textAlignment = .Center
            self.textFieldsText.append(textField)
            }
        addAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: .Default){ _ in
            self.titles.append(self.textFieldsText[0].text!)
            self.subjects.append(self.textFieldsText[1].text!)
            self.previews.append(self.textFieldsText[2].text!)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            self.textFieldsText.removeAll()
            })



    presentViewController(addAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

}

```
class previewViewController: UIViewController {
@IBAction func readButton(sender: UIButton) {
}
@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var subjectLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var shortPreviewLabel: UITextView!

var titlesString: String!
var subjectsString: String!
var previewsString: String!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Save, target: self, action: "saveChanges")

    titleLabel.text = titlesString
    subjectLabel.text = subjectsString
    shortPreviewLabel.text = previewsString

}
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {

        let dataToDetail = segue.destinationViewController as! detailViewController
        dataToDetail.textViewString = self.previewsString

    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Comment: firrst put some code.
do you mean the back button of the second vC ?

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: I added the code, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question right, this may help:

use this `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("showPreview", sender: indexPath.row)
}
```

use this `prepareForSegue`:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showPreview" {
        let destinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! previewViewController
        if let index = sender as? Int {
            destinationViewController.titlesString = self.titles[index]
            destinationViewController.subjectsString = self.subjects[index]
            destinationViewController.previewsString = self.previews[index]
        }
    }
}
```

And you need to have a segue from `ViewController` to `previewViewController` called "showPreview". Like this:

[image: segue instruction]

Comment: This semi-worked, now the data displays, but I have two segues animating, first an empty one and than the one with data following the first one in sequence. I had this problem before, thats why the code looks the way it is now. Im guessing that prepareForSegue automatically displays the empty segue followed by updated segue from didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: You should only have one segue in your storyboard called "showPreview". Remove the ones you alreade have, and try again. Use a segue directly from the view controller to the other view controller, see the screenshot i've added...

Comment: Thanks a lot Rapsefar, that worked. Just curious, I only ever had one segue "showPreview". Why didn't it work with the segue I had, which was the same as the one I replaced it with?

Comment: Hmm, yeah, that's the mystery. You must have made some small mistake with the first segues, it's hard for me to say, not knowing exactly what you've done.. But you're welcome.. I'm pleased to help :)

Comment: Yeah, truly a mystery, but now when I think about it, I did play around with the types of segues in a storyboard. At the end I did leave it as Push, but that might have messed it up. Anyway, thanks for the clarification :) I would up-vote your answer, but don't have enough "score" :) I will when I do.

Comment: You're welcome :) You should be able to accept my answer as the correct answer, by pressing checkmark..

Comment: There you go :) hate being a newbie :)